# Gitlab CI -Laravel 5.5 - PHPUnit "Tests\TestCase not found"

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I set up a Gitlab CI Pipeline for a Laravel 5.5 project (files at the bottom of the post) and the build is succeeding, but the tests fail because PHPUnit exits with the error message

> Fatal error: Class 'Tests\TestCase' not found in /builds/[User]/[Repo]/tests/Feature/DocumentTest.php on line 8

(Obviously, [User] and [Repo] aren't the real values, just don't wanna make it public here)

I've tried different things already, like installing PHPUnit globally, calling PHPUnit in different ways, it all ends up with the same error message.

PHPUnit is running successfully on my local (no matter HOW I call it, it always works). So anyone knows what the problem here might be?

For reference here are the pipeline files:

*.gitlab-ci.yml*:

```
image: woohuiren/php-laravel-env:latest

services:
  - mysql:latest
  - redis:4.0.2-alpine

before_script:
  - apk update
  - docker-php-ext-install pcntl

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

stages:
  - build
  - test

build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - sh .gitlab-build.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vendor/
      - bootstrap/
      - composer.phar
      - .env
  tags:
    - docker

test_job:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - build_job
  script:
    - sh .gitlab-ci.sh
  tags:
    - docker
```

*.gitlab-build.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

php -v
ping -c 3 mysql

php composer.phar install --no-progress --no-scripts

php artisan package:discover
cp -v .env.testing .env
php artisan key:generate
php artisan optimize
php artisan config:clear
php artisan storage:link
php artisan migrate --seed
php artisan jwt:secret
php artisan passport:install --force
```

*.gitlab-ci.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eo pipefail

php -v
ping -c 3 mysql

./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -v --testdox
```

Comment: Hey Sorry for the late reply. No your answer did not solve the problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks, Jan. Do you mind sharing how you solved the problem? I'm interested to learn what caused the issue.in this case.

Comment: No solution yet I'm afraid. I'm happy to update this thread if ever I'll resolve it though, I assume you'll get a notification if I ever I do so?

Comment: I'll get a notification if you @mention my name in the question comments (@CyRossignol) or if you comment on my answer. I don't mind helping to resolve this if you're open to providing a few more details to help diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is `Tests\TestCase`? I'm guessing *line 8* in *DocumentTest.php* is

```
public class DocumentTest extends TestCase
```

...where `TestCase` is `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`. It seems like there's an autoloading problem or the file doesn't import `TestCase`. Try changing this line to:

```
public class DocumentTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

I can try to give a better answer if you include the *phpunit.xml* and *composer.json*.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on local though. Make sure your `composer.json` has

```
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
```

run `composer dump-autoload` at least once or make it a part of your testing procedure.